# Changing order of parameters resolves linker error

Tags: c++

I have found some strange behavior in my code (this is just a snippet):

```
void StringSplit(string b,char splitchar,vector<string>& a) {}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    string b;
    getline(cin, b);
    vector<string> result1;
    StringSplit(b, ' ', result1);
    std::cout << result1[0];
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it, I get a  **`Linker command failed with exit code 1`**, but didn't see anything wrong with it.

Then I randomly change the order of the parameters of `StringSplit`, and the error is fixed:

```
void StringSplit(char splitchar,string b,vector<string>& a) {}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    string b;
    getline(cin, b);
    vector<string> result1;
    StringSplit(' ', b, result1);
    std::cout << result1[0];
    return 0;
}
```

Why does it do that?

Comment: Note: the order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified in C++.

Comment: @JesperJuhl True, but that can't affect the behaviour here since the arguments are all independent.

Comment: What is the rest of the linker error?

Comment: My guess is that your change forced a rebuild which would have solved the problem anyway, Without a [MCVE] for your original problem it is pretty much impossible to diagnose.

Comment: Are you sure that this is not just `Rebuild` effect?

Comment: Not the problem but `std::cout << result1[0];` is undefined behavior

Comment: You just "randomly" fixed the non-matching declaration and definition. Don't code "randomly" and always test the snippets you post (which both compile) to avoid humiliation.

Comment: @Niall It's too long,in brief it says "1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64"

Comment: @NathanOliver when I delete this,the problem I still exist.

Comment: You have two definitions for the function, same name, same signature. If the function definition is in a header you need inline and/or an include guard. If not, if they are different functions then you should chose a different name for the one. If they are the same function, then have the definition in a single cpp and the declaration in a header.

Comment: The root cause of the error is the duplicate symbols.

Comment: @AlanStokes I just leave out include statement of string,vector and iostream, i just test the code i wrote above,and i get the same problem. My compiler is g++ 4.2.1 and my operating system is OS X 10.11.4.

Comment: @Niall I include a file with the same function in another file of my project.

Comment: Given they are you projects, you can also explore namespaces to help with this.

Comment: I've condensed this into an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... ,in brief it says "1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64"

The root cause of the error is the duplicate symbols.

You have two definitions for the function, same name, same signature. If the function definition is in a header you need to inline and/or use an include guard. If not, if they are different functions then you should chose a different name for the one.

If they are the same function, then have the definition in a single cpp and the declaration in a header.

> I include a file with the same function in another file of my project.

Given they are your projects, you can also explore namespaces to help with this.